Is there a probe sonicator horn made of carborundum?
I consider buying a probe sonicator for an experiment, which needs the horn tip to be made of silicon carbide (aka carborundum), or at least surface covered with it.
Is it even possible to make such a thing, given that sound propagates better when the horn is made of an uniform density material? I guess the whole horn cannot be made of carborundum because its brittleness makes it unsuitable thread material (horns are usually attached to the ultrasound source via threads, AFAIK).
If it is possible, where do I get one?

I don't know about getting one, but it is possible to make one. Aim for "good enough" rather than "better"
